# Numeric value '%' is not recognized - Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is part of my query that is getting the error

```
WHEN D.ROLE_NAME LIKE '%' + B.Project_Phase + '%' 
 AND D.ROLE_NAME LIKE '%Clinical Consultant%' 
              THEN D.RESOURCE_NAME END AS "Clinical Consultant"
```

Am I missing some parenthesis? It works in SQL fine but can't get it to work in snowflake. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concatenate string in Snowflake you need to use **[||](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat.html)** operator instead of `+`:

```
CASE WHEN D.ROLE_NAME LIKE '%' || B.Project_Phase || '%' 
      AND D.ROLE_NAME LIKE '%Clinical Consultant%' 
THEN D.RESOURCE_NAME END AS "Clinical Consultant"
```

When `+` is used then implicit conversion occurs and that is the reason of the error: `Numeric value '%' is not recognized`